# Sum number of times statement is executed in triple nested loop

Tags: runtime-analysis, loops

I have this code fragment:

```
for( i=0; i<n; i++ )
    for( j=0; j<i; j++ )
        for( k=0; k<j; k++ )
            S;
```

I need to find the number of times that S is executed in that code block. I [plugged it into Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28sum%28sum%281%29%20from%20k=0%20to%20j%29%20from%20j=0%20to%20i%29%20from%20i=0%20to%20n) but I am not sure if that is the right answer.

I want to be able to do the math in order to figure the answer out so can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just start with n=1, and then do n=5 and n=10 and maybe some more and you should see the pattern to the equation for the number of times S is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wolfram Alpha answer isn't quite correct - you're off by one in each sum - the loop will iterate over $\{1,...,n-1\}$, not $\{1,...,n\}$, though other than that your reasoning is sound. What you should be asking W/A for is:

$$
\sum^{n-1}_{i=0}\sum^{i-1}_{j=0}\sum^{j-1}_{k=0} 1
$$

If you break the sums down bit by bit it gets a little easier to swallow, just start at the innermost sum and work outwards. It's probably fairly obvious that $\sum^{j-1}_{k=0}1 = j$, which breaks the triple-sum down into $\sum^{n-1}_{i=0}\sum^{i-1}_{j=0}j$.

We have that $\sum^{i-1}_{j=0}j = \frac{1}{2}(i^2-i)$, so what was a double sum is now the difference of two sums, $\frac{1}{2}(\sum^{n-1}_{i=0}i^2 - \sum^{n-1}_{i=0}i)$.

The second term has already been worked out, and we have that $\sum^{n-1}_{i=0}i^2 = \frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}$. From there, you should be able to work out your answer;

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum^{n-1}_{i=0}i^2 - \sum^{n-1}_{i=0}i\right)
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6} - \frac{3n(n-1)}{6} \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left((2n-1)\frac{n(n-1)}{6} - 3\frac{n(n-1)}{6} \right)\\
&= \frac{n(n-1)(2n-4)}{12}\\
&= \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}
\end{align*}

The results about the sum of the first $n-1$ numbers and the sum of the first $n-1$ square numbers are fairly standard ones - if you want some proofs of them then [this page](http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/ira/infinity/answers/sm_sq_cb.html) gives some nice arguments, though note that their sums end at $n$ and not $n-1$.